# Best method to encrypt passwords with php mssql

Tags: php, t-sql, passwords

What would be the best method for encrypting passwords in a database . In my case I have to encrypt two passwords per user : the user access and your own email account.

The first serious in one direction , comparing the entered password with the one stored in mssql , but the second need it in both directions ( encrypting and decrypting ) because I need it for the user is validated by sending an email through php .

The server I am using has installed PHP Version 5.5.33-1 ~ dotdeb + 7.1

Thank you very much to all.

Comment: don't encrypt; hash. To answer: `password_hash()`.

Comment: The best way would be to hash passwords not encrypt them. The function you would use for this is `password_hash`